# I am getting an undefined offset error after moving files into different folders

Tags: php, html, css

OK so I have a folder that looks like this..

```
loginsystem/
        homepages/
             home14.php

        includes/
             dbh.inc.php 

        header.php
        index.php
```

...When a user creates a new account on my website, they get a personal homepage (ex. homepages/home14).  I want to include the header I use for my index.php file inside of the home14.php file.  When I try to reroute the required location for home14.php, I get the undefined offset errors.  The errors say that problems are on lines 29 and 30 of the header.php file, but it's working perfectly fine for index.php.

When I link to the header in my home14.php file, I typed (require "../header.php";)

header.php

```
<?php  
    require 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
    session_start();
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
    include 'includes/comments.inc.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
</head>
        <div id="headerContainer">

<!-- If the user is logged in, set username and profile picture.-->

<?php 
                if (isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
                    $id = $_SESSION['userID'];
                    $sqlImg = "SELECT * FROM profileimg WHERE userid='$id'";
                    $resultImg = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlImg);
                    while ($rowImg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultImg)) {      
                        if ($rowImg['status'] == 0) {
                            $filename = "profilepics/profile".$id."*";
                            $fileinfo = glob($filename);
       -------- LINE 29 --- $fileext = explode(".", $fileinfo[0]);
       -------- LINE 30 --- $fileactualext = $fileext[1];
                            echo "<div class=userPicture><img src='profilepics/profile".$id.".".$fileactualext."?".mt_rand()."'></div>";
                        }
                        else {
                            echo "<div class='userPicture'><img src='profilepics/noUser.png'></div>";
                        }
                    }
```

home14.php

```
<?php
    require "../header.php";
    if (isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
        echo 
            "<div class='homeBody'>



            </div>";
        require "../footer.php";    
    } 
    else {
        header("Location: ../signup.php");
        exit();
    }

?>
```

Again, all I want is the same header I use in the index.php file to be used in the home14.php file.  I am only getting the undefined offset when I require it in the home14.php and not when I use it with index.php

Comment: Which ones are the lines 29 and 30? Please mark them in your code

Comment: It's telling me I can't re-declare comments.inc.php
and requiring dbh.inc.php didn't seem to have an effect ;/ 

thank you for the comment though

Comment: Please post the error in detail

Comment: Your file structure is not appropriate, to achieve what are you doing above, check out below link https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths, you can use realpath() method or simple __ FILE __ before includes to make them work every where.

Comment: I have now marked lines 29 and 30

Comment: The error your are getting on these lines is because "profilepics" directory is not available under homepages/ directory when you include header.php in home14.php. So, you need to provide the absolute path for the directories you are using in header.php to make it work everywhere .

Comment: Ok, thank you but I don't know how to do that.  Could you explain by writing out the code I should use?

Comment: Change `require 'includes/dbh.inc.php';` to `require realpath().'includes/dbh.inc.php';` and on line 27 change it to `$filename = realpath()."/profilepics/profile".$id."*";` . You probably need to debug your code by using echo etc. to see the appropriate output of realpath();

Comment: Now I am getting this error Warning: realpath() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginsystem\header.php on line 2

I have never seen realpath before I'm sorry

Comment: That is what I said, you need to debug it. Try using __ FILE __ instead of realpath()